# Can candles of invocation be used to farm wishes to gain way too much gp?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

A [*candle of invocation*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/candle-of-invocation/) has a price of 8,400 gold. The *candle* can be used to call a [pasha](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/genie/shaitan/shaitan-pasha/) who can grant three wishes. Each wish can be sold for 21,000 gold. Is it possible for a character to buy *candles* and repeat this process until he can buy his own kingdom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a DM disallow the Candle of Invocation exploit using RAW?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/can-a-dm-disallow-the-candle-of-invocation-exploit-using-raw)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question, for two important reasons: You can't _wish_ for another Candle in PF, making the core of the "chain-gate efreets" not work, and this question is asking from the point of view of the player; asking if it's possible, not how to ban it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, for several reasons.

The first reason is that you can't control a Pasha with a Candle of Invocation. The Candle has a caster level of 17, and a Pasha has 18 hit dice. This means that the Pasha isn't automatically controlled when you summon it with a *gate* spell, and would need to be negotiated with for services.

The second reason is that selling *wishes* like that isn't as trivial as you make it sound. Finding a buyer for powerful magic like that isn't something that can be done automatically, and being able to pull that trick more than a few times in a row would require some significant DM agreement to hand you unlimited money.

Next is that it isn't necessarily a given that a DM will ignore the 10,000 gp cost of using the summoning side of the Candle's *gate* ability. It would be kind of weird if you could shave off 6,000 gp off the cost of a *gate* just by making a Candle of Invocation first, so you might also be on the hook for that material cost as well.

Finally, Pashas have *plane shift* as an at-will ability, and probably wouldn't take kindly to being repeatedly summoned and forced to grant *wishes*. Remember that a calling spell like *gate* is calling an actual creature from somewhere else in the multiverse, and that creature will remember what you've been calling it for.

Comment: Your heading is misleading: you say No, and it reads as a rejection of the title question, but in reality you are only rejecting the particular approach suggested in the question, when other approaches are entirely plausible.